# What is the probability that All people select the same thing

Tags: probability, problem-solving, word-problem

If we have 3 types of things that were given for 4 people 
what the probability that all people will select the same thing, if they can select what they want

Or have to get more information to solve this problem? 
More information in the problem given 32 things that have 3 types (A,B,C) 
A - 10 things
B - 8 things
C - 14 things

Thanks for answer

Comment: Are vanilla ice and broccoli two of the three things? That mght influence the result ...

Comment: It sounds like you want to say, "What is the probability that all people select the same TYPE of thing?", but you said thing instead of type of thing. Also, can two people choose the same exact thing of a given type? Or when someone chooses one of the things, then it is removed so other people can't choose it? (Although they can choose other things of the same type).

Comment: Your problem is not clear. I have made some assumptions in my partial Answer to help you clarify the problem and maybe get started on an answer. On this site we expect you to show your thoughts and what you have tried--partly to avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not solvable unless each person selects items at random. Also, certainly, one does need to know how many items there are of each type. 
Still the statement is a bit vague. I suppose each person will pick exactly one item.

It seems you want $P(\text{all 4 select } A) + P(\text{all 4 select }B) + P(\text {all 4 select }C).$ Does that seem correct? If so, what
rule of probability is involved?

Then if items are selected without replacement $$P(\text{all 4 select} A) = (10/32)(9/31)(8/30)(7/29),$$
but if items are selected with replacement, it is
$$P(\text{all 4 select} A) = (10/32)^4.$$

My guess it is sampling 'without replacement', but you need to
make it clear.

From there, you should be able to finish the problem.

If my guesses as to the interpretation of this problem are not
what you have in mind, then please say what you $do$ have in mind.
Either way, maybe you should edit your problem so it is more
specific.